# Get entries with a specific post date

Tags: query, postdate

I'm having absolute brain fog right now.

I'm trying to show a list of entries with a given `postDate`

```
{% set startDate = startDate ?? now|date('Y-m-d') %}

craft.entries
.section(['jobs', 'userPostedJobs'])
.authorId(user.id)
.postDate(">=" ~ startDate)
```

Am I right in saying though that if my date was `2022-04-16` that this would include all entries after that date also?

Have also looked at `.postDate(['and', ">= #{startDate}", "< #{startDate}"])` that yields no results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’d need to define a range that begins today and ends tomorrow.

```
{% set startDate = startDate ?? now %}
{% set endDate = startDate|date_modify('+1 day') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries()
  .section(['jobs', 'userPostedJobs'])
  .authorId(user.id)
  .postDate([
    'and',
    ">= #{startDate|date('Y-m-d')}",
    "< #{endDate|date('Y-m-d')}"
  ])
  .all() %}
```